# Double conversion from String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, numbers, double

I am trying to get input from a user in one line, then splitting it into its respective variable. For example, my input could be "5 kg to gram", so the program would take the input, split it with a " " delimiter, then set the respective variables with their respective indices. Here's the **code**:

```
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
var inputArray: Array<String>
var input: String
var baseNumber: Double
var finalNumber: Double
var baseUnit: Unit
var finalUnit: Unit
while (true) {
    print("Enter a number and a measure of length: ")
    input = scanner.nextLine()
    if (input == "exit") return
    inputArray = input.split(" ").toTypedArray()
    println(input[0])
    baseNumber = input[0].toDouble()
    baseUnit = getUnit(inputArray[1])
    finalUnit = getUnit(inputArray[3])
...}
```

However, the **baseNumber** variable that holds the number does not seem to work. For example, if I type the input like above (5 kg to grams), the baseNumber variable somehow becomes 53.0.

I am new at Kotlin, so I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `baseNumber = inputArray[0].toDouble()`

Comment: I cannot believe I overlooked that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the value of the `char`. The ASCII value of the character `5` is `53`, so you need to convert the *String* `"5"` to a Double.

```kotlin
'5'.toDouble() // 53.0

"5".toDouble() // 5.0
```